# Looking for a file/cli tool to determine monitor status/statistics

Tags: display, xrandr

Current Use Case: I have a NodeJS application, in Docker, querying `xrandr`, every 10 seconds, to make sure a monitor is still connected. I hold a current state (`connected`); if it changes from `disconnected` -> `connected`, I send setup commands:

1. Rotate screen (`xrandr -o left`)
2. Set resolution (1920x1080)

However, I would not like to continually poll `xrandr` like this. Is there another option (such as setting up a fs watch on a hw file, if that even makes sense and is possible) that I can do?

Use Cases:

1. Know when the monitor has been disconnected/reconnected
2. On reconnect, rotate display and set custom resolution
3. Preferably not have to poll `xrandr` anymore

Comment: Begin with seeing if any process reports monitor disconnect/reconnect. Wait until it happens, then `journalctl --since="-3 minutes"` will show you logs. `journalctl`'s `-S`, `--since=`, `-U`, and `--until=` switches accept times/dates like "2012-10-30 18:17:16"  (`date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`. See `man systemd.time`)

Comment: tail the Xorg.log , it will often report EDID info which identifies each monitor upon plug/unplug. Of course X11 has to be running in the first place for this to work. This can be combined with grep and other pipelines to trigger output. Another good tool is udevadm , which is specific to monitoring hardware connect/disconnect

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Thanks so much, I'll let you know what I found.

Comment: @waltinator Thank you, I'll let you know if I found anything!